# Is there a way to disable specific export options in HighChart 5.0.14?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I got HighChart 5.0.14 with the exporting.js module and the export-data module.

I'll have 7 exporting-options now: PNG,JPEG,PDF,SVG,CSV,XLS,ViewDataTable in my chart.

What i really need is PNG JPEG and CSV, is there a simple way to disable the other options? I can only find the all or nothing-possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `menuItems` property for this.

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems